# Можно ли совместить generic type двух разных классов в Java?

Tags: java, generics

Делаю андроид приложение. На DataBinding описываю смену врагментов в рамках одной активити. Сделал класс Sequense, который управляет фрагментами и enum'ы, которые описывают флоу фрагментов в рамках каждой активити. Так как наследовать enum мы не можем, то сделал для них интерфейс Screen где определил некоторые методы. Выглядит это приблизительно так (проблему опишу в комментариях)

```
public class Sequence<T extends Enum<T> & Sequence.Screen> extends BaseObservableField<FragmentIntent> {


    ........

    // Такой метод работает адекватно
    public T nextScreen() {
        Enum[] values = currentScreen.getValues();
        .........
    }

    // Но если мы пытаемся кастить getValues к T, то получаем ошибку о несовместимости 
    // Enum[] и T[] хотя и в Screen и в Sequence тип T описан одинаково 
    // в строке T[] values = currentScreen.getValues();
    public T prevScreen() {
        T[] values = currentScreen.getValues();
        .......
    }

    ..................

    public interface Screen<T extends Enum<T> & Sequence.Screen> {

        T[] getValues();

        ..............

    }
}
```

Можно ли как то сделать финт ушами с дженериками, чтобы мне не приходилось кастить каждый элемент массива к T, да и вообще это не очень то типобезопасно. Мне пока в голову не приходит ни одного решения.

пример класса, расширенного интерфейсом Screen

```
public enum CorpEditTemplateScreen implements Sequence.Screen {

    ....................

    @Override
    public CorpEditTemplateScreen[] getValues() {
        return values();
    }
}
```

Comment: Массивы и Generics из разных областей. Их не стоит совмещать.

Comment: По возможности сократите код до минимально возможного примера. В текущую версию вчитываться, скорее всего, никто не будет.